Manga where a girl is abused by her adopted family then gets rescued by her real family, who are cursed
I'm looking for a manga where a girl is abused by her adopted family (they may have kidnapped her?) when she gets rescued by her real family.
Her real family is apparently cursed (they kill/are aggressive) so the wives never stay with the family but there was a prophecy that said that if a girl was born in the family, the curse was broken.
Now a bunch of women think they can seduce her brothers but they only have an eye for her (they adore her).
I also remember that her eyes change depending on her emotions (it's a trait for all royalty her real family).
It was technically a manhwa (full colour) and was being translated into English (had already at least 10 chapters translated).
I personally found it via a YouTube recommendations video.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

This question is very terse and could be dramatically improved by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

thanks davidW
i made some changes hope its beter now

Huh... I could swear we've had this one before, but I'm not finding it.

fuzzyBoots i think sombody found it
but thank a lot for looking

will this qwestion be deleted ?

@por42 - The question won't be deleted. We just have a rule that when two or more story-ID questions are confirmed (by the author of the question) to be asking about the same story, only one of them should remain open while any others should be closed as duplicates. The duplicates remain on the site; they just can't receive additional answers.

ah ok thanks i was afraid as the other qwestion had way less to go on

Is this My Three Tyrant Brothers...?

All members of the Ascania imperial family are cursed to die at the hands of a loved one, a curse only broken by the birth of a girl into the bloodline. So when a young slave girl with the telltale, color-changing Ascania eyes is discovered, she’s declared Princess Chloe, the little sister of the three princes. She’s excited to finally have a family, but her new brothers seem a bit strange… They’ve always had to be cold and unfeeling for their own protection, but will Chloe’s arrival plant the seed of change in their hearts?


The blonde female lead, Wednesday, is initially one of several child slaves working in the house of an abusive slave trader.
One day, Crown Prince Chester shows up and determines by looking at her eyes (which change colour with her mood, a trait unique to the royal bloodline) that she's Princess Chloe, the illegitimate daughter of the the Emperor that the royal family have been searching for. He then takes her home to meet her other two brothers. It's noted that while her hair isn't platinum blonde like that of her brothers, Lady Erika had a similar hair colour to her.
The royal family has a curse placed on them as punishment for the first emperor's sins and don't normally produce female offspring, but it's said that if a female child is born from the family, the curse will be released.
You can read the manhwa at Tapas.

Ah, and that would explain that.

im i'm pretty sure this is it thanks a lot

@LogicDictates thanks and sorry did not know that new to the site
